# _TypeError (type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget')

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

am trying to call the user from data (am using firebase as database)
the profile page not working for more understanding check the other issue i posted last day :
[FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable , and how to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74223375/firebaseexception-cloud-firestore-unavailable-the-service-is-currently-unavai/74228594#74228594)

```dart
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:yumor/models/progress.dart';
import 'package:yumor/models/user_model.dart';

class profile extends StatefulWidget {
  const profile({Key? key,required this.userProfile}) : super(key: key);
  final String? userProfile;


  

  @override
  State<profile> createState() => _profileState();
}

class _profileState extends State<profile> {
  final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  buildprofileheader() async{
    final doc=await userRef.doc(widget.userProfile).get();
      if(doc.exists){ 
        var data=doc.data();
      }
    return FutureBuilder(future:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userRef.id).get(),
    builder: ((context, snapshot) {
      if(!snapshot.hasData){
        return CircularProgress();
      }
      UserModel user=UserModel.fromMap(Map);
      return Padding(padding:EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
                  Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.account_circle, size: 90,)
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Text(
              user.Username as String,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize:16.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      );
    }),
       );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            "Profile",
          ),
        ),
        body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
           buildprofileheader(), // the error shows in this line <=======
        ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `buildprofileheader` return type is `Future<Widget>` but it should be `Widget` in order to use in `ListView`, so you need to use an other `FutureBuilder` to get `userRef`. So just wrap your current `FutureBuilder` with an other one.

Answer (score 1):

As for the logic part, you can simplify the logic for future method something like

```dart
  Future<UserModel?> getData() async {
  try{
    final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    final doc = await userRef.doc(widget.userProfile).get();
    if (doc.exists) {
      var data = doc.data(); // not sure about this use case
    } else {
      return null;
    }

    final data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userRef.id)
        .get();

    if (data.exists) {
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromMap(data);
      return user;
    }
  } catch(e){ }
 
  }
```

Create a state variable for future method , and use like

```
late final future = getData(); 

Widget buildprofileheader() {
    return FutureBuilder<UserModel?>(
      future: future,
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return CircularProgress();
        }
        return Padding(....
```

```dart
class _profileState extends State<profile> {

  Future<UserModel?> getData() async {
    final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    final doc = await userRef.doc(widget.userProfile).get();
    if (doc.exists) {
      var data = doc.data(); // not sure about this use case
    } else {
      return null;
    }

    final data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userRef.id)
        .get();

    if (data.exists) {
      UserModel user = UserModel.fromMap(data);
      return user;
    }
  }

  late final future = getData();

  Widget buildprofileheader() {
    return FutureBuilder<UserModel?>(
      future: future,
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(
                    Icons.account_circle,
                    size: 90,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Text(
                  user.Username as String,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(
            "Profile",
          ),
        ),
        body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
          buildprofileheader(),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: after i tried you code i still got this error message in this line of code `  external static Never _throw(Object error, StackTrace stackTrace);
`

Comment: seems like the issue is from `getData`, can put everything inside try catch blocks here

Comment: tell me everything you need and i will put it here

Comment: try top level part

Comment: sorry i did understand what you mean

Comment: now am re-debugging the code and see what changed

Comment: i think the problem is on the condition `if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }`